# gradle build failure for groovy project on dependence

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

New to groovy, and I had one [groovy project@commit 2f54b59](https://github.com/larrycai/gradle-sample/tree/2f54b59cd1012bd96570f8bc2eb03cad50e303fb) like below

```
├── build.gradle
└── src
    └── main
        └── groovy
            ├── check.groovy
            └── helpers
                └── Person.groovy
```

And the `check.groovy` is simple:

```
import helpers.*
println "hello"
person = new Person()
```

I try to use `build.gradle` to manage the project with `sourceSets`

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDirs('.')
            include '*.groovy'
        }
    }
}
```

and meet error when build:

```
$ gradle build
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy
startup failed:
gradle-sample/src/main/check.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class Person
 @ line 5, column 10.
   person = new Person()
            ^

1 error
:compileGroovy FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

If u run the `groovy` command directly, it works fine

```
$ cd src/main/groovy
$ groovy check.groovy
hello
```

How to setup the configuration to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to configure any source sets - gradle will handle it itself.

See a little demo [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/46467200).

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
}
```

Comment: your demo is for java, it doesn't compile my groovy code when I applied there

Comment: @LarryCai, yes I've changed it. Wrong plugin was applied - thanks!

Comment: can u try to keep that sourceSets part, the real example has customized directory and more complicated files

Comment: @LarryCai why have you changed the source sets?

Comment: i had legacy code base, put groovy in different folder (lib and root), will be good to explain the sourceSet as well (paste some codes), so I will accept the answer. they are used with jobdsl